# Anyone knows the reference for this formula or can derive them in Spherical coordinates?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

I have used the formula which is available on a website to calculate the destination longitude and latitude based-on current long/lat, distance to destination and bearing. For example,long/lat of a point on earth is given and the goal is calculating long/lat of a point which is located 1km away from start point. Here is the formula:

[φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

[λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

I implemented the formula with my desired programming language and the formula works with no problem, but I need the reference for this formula. In other words, I want to understand how this formula is derived analytically. I already sent the writer an email to ask about the reference but no reply yet. I'm wondering anyone knows the reference for this formula or any similar formula? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowns: start point $(\varphi_1$, $\lambda_1)$, heading $\theta$, radius $r$, distance $d$.

By the law of spherical cosines, we know that:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\cos(\delta) = \sin(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2) + \cos(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2)\cos(\Delta\lambda)
\end{equation}
defines the angular distance, which means the arclength formula on a sphere gives 
$\delta = d/r $, which is easily computed.

Next, comes a tougher part. (see [here](http://www.nosco.ch/mathematics/en/great-circle.php)).
Consider the spherical triangle generated between the two points and the north pole. Let $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ be the angles between the north pole (with which the heading is defined) and the points. The law of spherical cosines then gives:
$$
\cos(\psi_2) = \cos(\psi_1)\cos(\delta)+\sin(\psi_1)\sin(\delta)\cos(\theta)
$$
$$
\therefore\; \cos(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\psi_2) - \cos(\psi_1)\cos(\delta)}{\sin(\psi_1)\sin(\delta)}
$$
But then using $\psi_i = \pi/2 - \varphi_i$, we get:
$$\tag{2}
\cos(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\varphi_2) - \sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\delta)}{\cos(\varphi_1)\sin(\delta)}
$$
This lets us solve for $\varphi_2$ as:
$$\tag{$\ast$}
\varphi_2 = \arcsin\left(
\cos(\varphi_1)\sin(\delta)\cos(\theta) + \sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\delta)
\right)
$$
Note it is also possible to express $\theta$ without the angular distance via:
$$ \tag{3}\tan(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\Delta\lambda)\cos(\varphi_2)}{\cos(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)-\sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2)\cos(\Delta\lambda)} $$

Now for $\lambda_2$. The first equation we wrote tells us that:
$$\tag{4}
\cos(\Delta\lambda) = \frac{\cos(\delta) - \sin(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)}{
\cos(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2)}
$$
Furthermore, using the expression for $\tan(\theta)$ (eq 3) we can get $\sin(\Delta\lambda)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta)\left[
\cos(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2) - \sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2)\cos(\Delta\lambda)\right]
 &=
\sin(\Delta\lambda)\cos(\varphi_2)\cos(\theta)
\end{align}
Next, substitute in eqs 2 and 4, to get:
$$
\sin(\Delta\lambda) = \frac{\sin(\theta)\sin(\delta)}{\cos(\varphi_2)}
$$
Thus, we get a formula for the tangent via:
$$
\tan(\Delta\lambda) = \frac{\sin(\Delta\lambda)}{\cos(\Delta\lambda)}
=
\frac{\cos(\varphi_1)\sin(\theta)\sin(\delta)}{\cos(\delta) - \sin(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)}
$$
Solving for $\lambda_2$ gives us:
$$\tag{$\dagger$}
\lambda_2 = \lambda_1 + \arctan\left(\frac{\cos(\varphi_1)\sin(\theta)\sin(\delta)}{\cos(\delta) - \sin(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)}\right)
$$
The formulas we wished to derive are exactly those seen in eqs $\ast$ and $\dagger$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @user8296976 You're welcome :)