# Found a formula supposedly from the spherical law of cosines but I don't know how it comes from there

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I need to convert Cartesian coordinates to lat/long coordinates or to be more specific: I have a point $P(\phi_1|\lambda_1)$ (lat/long), a heading $\theta$ (like compass heading, north is $0^{\circ}$) and a distance $d$ (from which you can calculate $\delta=d/r$). I found some formulae for this and their derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2365306/514323). However, I can't find (out) how the equation

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\cos(\delta) = \sin(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2) + \cos(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2)\cos(\Delta\lambda)
\end{equation}

is built from the spherical law of cosines as the spherical law of cosines only gives

\begin{equation}
\cos(a) = \cos(b)\cos(c) + \sin(b)\sin(c)\cos(A)
\end{equation}

and their cyclic permutations for $\cos(b)$ and $\cos(c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spherical triangle  you are interested in has a vertex at the north pole. The angular distance to the other two vertices is $90$ degrees minus their latitude, hence $\sin$ gets swapped with $\cos$.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I actually already had the same problem when trying to understand how eq. 2 was built (see link) but didn't think that would be the solution for this one as it was the first equation written in the derivation. I stand corrected.

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes the obvious escapes one.