# Where does this formula for tan(θ) come from?

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I am trying to understand the derivation of formulae for converting cartesian coordinates to latitude/longitude. I found a detailed description [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364154/anyone-knows-the-reference-for-this-formula-or-can-derive-them-in-spherical-coor) (check link for more details) but it is not mentioned how the equation
$$ \tag{3}\tan(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\Delta\lambda)\cos(\varphi_2)}{\cos(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)-\sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2)\cos(\Delta\lambda)} $$
is built.

Comment: What are $\theta$, $\varphi_1$, $\varphi_2$ and $\Delta\lambda$?

Comment: @ajotatxe Check the hyperlink [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364154/anyone-knows-the-reference-for-this-formula-or-can-derive-them-in-spherical-coor) as linked in the question for all the details, but $\theta$ is the bearing to point 2, $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are the latitudes of point one and two respectively and $\Delta\lambda$ is the difference in longitudes of the two points.